# VBScript WMI Class and Property Exist

Tags: vbscript, wmi

My company is trying to find what machines were not loaded with our images. We added in WMI a class called Revision_Detail, but due to inconsistencies, it was not populated on all versions of our images.

I put together the below to check if the Revision_Detail exists, then check if it is not null. If it is null it reverts to ImageRevision class, which everyone of our images has.

My problem is the function I came across (and are using), cycles through all of CIMV2 classes and is a bit slow.

Is there a way to just execute the query and catch the error that Revision Detail doesn't exists?

```
Function WMIClassExists(strComputer, WMIClassName)
    WMIClassExists = vbFalse 
    Dim objWMIService: Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
    Dim colClasses: Set colClasses = objWMIService.SubclassesOf() 
    Dim objClass 
    For Each objClass In colClasses 
        if instr(objClass.Path_.Path,WMIClassName) Then 
            WMIClassExists = vbTrue 
        End if 
    Next 
    Set objWMIService = Nothing 
    Set colClasses = Nothing 
End Function

Set wshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network") 

strComputer = wshNetwork.ComputerName 

If WMIClassExists(strComputer,"Revision_Detail") Then
    'Found Revision_Detail
    WSCript.Echo strWMIClass & " WMI class does exists on " & strComputer 
    Set Wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\ROOT\CIMV2") 
    SET colItems = Wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Revision_Detail")

    For Each objItem in colItems
        if IsNull(objItem.CurrentBuild) Then
            'If CurrentBuild doesnt exist, check ImageRevision
            SET colItems2 = Wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM ImageRevision")

            For Each objItem2 in colItems2 
                wscript.echo "ImageRevision: " & objItem2.ImageRevision
            Next            
        else
            'Revision_Detail exists and is not blank
            wscript.echo "CurrentBuild: " & objItem.CurrentBuild
            wscript.echo "StartBuild: " & objItem.StartBuild
        end if
    Next

Else 
    'Must not be an our image
    WSCript.Echo strWMIClass & " WMI class does not exists on " & strComputer 
End if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to just execute the query and catch the error that Revision Detail doesn't exists?

Sure that's possible. Catching errors in VBScript is done with `On Error Resume Next` ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53f3k80h(v=vs.84).aspx)).

Since the WMI object collections are a bit awkward to work with, I have created a helper function that executes a WMI query and returns an array instead of a collection:

```
Function GetWmiObjects(wmi, wql)
    Dim items, item, i, result
    Set items = wmi.ExecQuery(wql)

    ' count items 
    On Error Resume Next
    i = 0
    For Each item In items
        If Err.Number = 0 Then i = i + 1
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' allocate array of the proper size
    ReDim result(i - 1)

    ' transfer items to array
    If i > 0 Then
        i = 0
        For Each item In items
            Set result(i) = item
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End If

    GetWmiObjects = result
End Function
```

Now it's easy to do:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\ROOT\CIMV2")

Revision_Detail = GetWmiObjects(wmi, "SELECT * FROM Revision_Detail")

If Count(Revision_Detail) = 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo "Revision_Detail not found"
Else
    Wscript.Echo Revision_Detail(0).CurrentBuild
End If
```

where `Count` is a convenience function that returns the size of an array:

```
Function Count(array)
    Count = UBound(array) + 1
End Function
```

Comment: I am receiving Object required: 'Revision_Detail(...)' on this line "Revision_Detail = GetWmiObjects(wmi, "SELECT * FROM Revision_Detail")"

Comment: Oops, that's fixed. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that it can be done but you'll have to wait for objWMIService to timeout every time it's ping a device that is down. 
Conversely you can take a call me when your ready approach. 
Create a script that check for the image on the local machine and saves it's findings to a file on the sever.  You can then have Group Policy schedule a task on all the machines to run new script locally.

**Updated:**
I tightened up your code a bit to reducing the overall complexity.

> On Error Resume Next

And

> On Error GoTo 0

Needed to be move inside the for each loop.  Since On Error GoTo 0 was outside the loop the Err object couldn't be reset to 0 until the for each loop exited.

```
Function GetWmiObjects(wmi, wql)
    Dim items, item, i, result
    Set items = wmi.ExecQuery(wql)

    For Each item In items
        On Error Resume Next
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            i = UBound(result) + 1
            ReDim Preserve result(i)
            Set result(i) = item
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next

    GetWmiObjects = result
End Function
```

Comment: Precisely what I am doing. Just wanted a script that ran faster to prevent degradation to the user.